# Resetting a seekbar in Android

Tags: android, slider, seekbar

In an activity, I have 5 seekbars whose values ranges from 0 to 10.
The user can change the value of all the seekbars.
I want all the seekbars to set themselves to zero once the user clicks reset button present in the same activity. Is there any function called slider.set ? I did not find any yet. What other method can be implemented ?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

> android:progress="5"

in your xml file. Alternatively, in java:

```
seekbar.setProgress(5);
```